# Angular 2 phone number Format

Tags: angular, pipe

Currently I have 0001-503-625-5599 phone number, so I would like to get (503)625-5599 is there any pipe for Angular 2 I can use? or any idea?.

Thanks

Comment: Nope.  They don't provide complex pipes for you -- you'll have to write your own.

Comment: Writing a custom pipe to do something like this should be relatively simple. Could you please elaborate a bit more, will you always want to truncate the first 4 digits? Does the length never change?

Comment: Please provide the code you've written so far and point to the lines where you got stuck.

Answer (score -3):

Written a Custom Pipe to format the given phone number.

URL: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rk3neo

```
<div> {{ phoneNo | phone:'(XXX)XXX-XXXX'}} </div>
```

To make it simple, you can use Regular Expression.